# How to send mail from Stored Procedure?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, email, sp-send-dbmail

I need to send a mail from Stored Procedure. I knew it is possible. I studied it from this [link](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/sending-smtp-mail-using-a-stored-procedure) . How do i authenticat in SMTP Server. Do you have any idea.?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You can use SQL Database Mail.

See [Database Mail and SQL Mail Stored Procedures (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177580.aspx)

And here's a [Tutorial](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3626056/Database-Mail-in-SQL-Server-2005.htm)

Comment: How to authenticate the sender?
Thanks.

Comment: Have you created a profile in Database Mail? You can specify credentials there. Management Studio > Management > Database Mail > New Profile

Answer (score 0):

Using extended stored procedures to create an use and ActiveX that sends the email or create an assembly that sends the mails and use it from sql2008.