# Send email from PL/SQL when a value is something

Tags: sql, oracle

How can I set PLSQL Oracle procedure to send me email, only in the case when some value in a table is "COMPLETE"?

Thank you.

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177267/how-to-send-mail-from-stored-procedure

Comment: @Java-DK - link is for sql server

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can do something like

Assigning values to PL SQL variables

```
<You can use select statement and push that value into the variable from table>
```

If condition

```
<You can check value here if its matching your criteria>

           true condition <send an email>
           put your email sending code here 

else 

           false condition <dont send an email>
```