# How to send mail from stored procedure after a successful insert : MSSQL 2017

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2017

I am new to SQL ,Here I need to send conformation mail to the user when an new user account is created .

If the user account is created successfully I need to send a conformation to that specific user from the stored procedure itself .

Technically : **Once the user data is inserted into the table I need to send mail from the same stored procedure itself** .

I have searched a lot in stackoverflow but I can't find a solution .

Can anyone help me to solve this.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177267/how-to-send-mail-from-stored-procedure
Maybe this can solve your problem

Comment: How is the actual used account being created in C# app, TSql, etc) @Zhu

Comment: I couldn't understand what you are asking for ? @MarkKram

Answer (score 0):

You can call sp_send_dbmail within your stored procedure.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-send-dbmail-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017